# How do I fix - 'File Containms no Section Headers error?

Tags: python, ini

Trying to get some data out of an .ini file using this code, when I try to open the .ini it gives     What Am I doing wrong?

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read('FILE.ini') #throws file contains no section headers
print(config['DEFAULT']['toAddr'])
x = config.get('DEFAULT', 'to')
```

The .ini file

```
['DEFAULT']
to = "blah"
```

I'm using Python 3.7 64 on Win 10

Comment: What is expected behavior, what is current problem? `when I try to open the .ini it gives What Am I doing wrong?` - did you missed a part of sentence?

Comment: Read [module-configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser)

Answer (score 1):

The header in the ini-file should not have quotes in it.

Use

```
[DEFAULT]
to = "blah"
```

instead of

```
['DEFAULT']
to = "blah"
```

Comment: No, same error, does not work. Missing something here, way more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Tried changing the .ini to .cfg? no joy, simply does not work. Same error. Is there any other method for storing user setting beyond configparser? it seems to be non functional in 3.7 64bit?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it working, so far, not sure why thought.